# Fibration of a toric symplectic manifold from a fibration of the moment polytope

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties

This question is regarding fiber bundles, both whose fibers and total space are toric symplectic manifolds. The structure group on the fiber is a subgroup of the structure group of the total space.

Suppose $X$ is a toric symplectic manifold with the action of a torus $T$. Let $H \subset T$ be a subgroup, and let $\mu_H$ be the induced moment map of the $H$-action. I assume that for all choices of  $c \in \operatorname{im}(\mu_H)$, the symplectic quotients $\mu_H^{-1}(c)/H$ are diffeomorphic. Then, one can see that $X$ is a symplectic fiber bundle whose fiber is the symplectic toric manifold given by the polytope $\mu_H(X)$, and base space is $\mu_H^{-1}(c)/H$ for any $c$. 
However the choice of the projection map $\pi:X \to B$ is not unique. We require projection maps to be $T$-equivariant and $H$-invariant. Any projection corresponds to a fibration of the moment polytope $\mu(X)$ with fibers $\mu_H(X)$. Is the converse true -- given a fibration of the moment polytope, can one construct a projection $\pi:X \to B$?

This looks true, but messy to prove. I would like to have a reference.

Comment: I am confused since $H \subset T$ doesn't even need to be a Lie group (so I don't understand "let $\mu_{H}$ be the induced moment map..."), for example consider the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \subset S^{1}$ generated by $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}$. I guess you assume $H$ is isomorphic to a lower dimensional torus?

Comment: Yes, Nick L, I assume $H$ to be a lower dimensional torus.